# Centering a layout containing items

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have created a Panel like this.

[image]

The fiddle for the panel is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/liaK/74R3m/) .

I want the buttons, Set Settings and Cancel to be at the center of this panel.

I tried setting `autoEl` with `center` tag but no luck. I haven't used form panel because I don't want all the items to be stretched.

How I can achieve this in Extjs4?

Comment: make them `display` as `inline` and to the container you add `text-align:center;`
your fiddle isnt showing anything

Comment: Test your fiddle before linking it!

Comment: @Breezer, if you run my fiddle it wont show anything, beacuse i have added  only the relevant code in the fiddle, instead of all the controller, viewport and other necessary dependencies..

Comment: @liaK and that kills the entire purpose with having a fiddle, but did you try what i suggested to you

Comment: @Breezer, as dependencies in Extjs4, you have add to another 3-4 files by that which I thought people would lose to understand where the pblm code lies. For your suggestion, am still learning extjs and javascript/css.. i thought some other options are available in extjs itself to achieve this.. i will try yours and let you know..

Answer (score 0):

Because 'hbox' layout (that you have used it for your panel Layout) is absolute layout, you have to do some css tricks to get to the point. Edit yout JS part of the buttons like this:

```
xtype: 'panel',
cls: 'mypanel', // Add CSS Class
layout: 'hbox', // Don't need align: 'stretch'
items:[{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Set Settings'
},{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Cancel',
    cls: 'btn-gap' // Instead of your Box item (for gap between 2 buttons)
}
```

And your custom CSS file will do the trick:

```
.x-panel.mypanel {
        text-align: center;
}
.x-panel.mypanel .x-btn {
        position: static !important;
}
.x-panel.mypanel .x-btn.btn-gap {
        margin-left: 25px !important;
}
```

There are some other ways to do this but this is the one that first came to my mind and it is simple too.